# Visual Basic 2010, Picturebox resource && Variable?

Tags: c#, variables, picturebox, string-concatenation

I've tried finding the solution but to no avail. I believe what i want is string concatenation...

I have a variable `"pictureid=face2"`
in my resources folder i have a picture called `"face2.jpg"`.
On the form i have a picture box.

This is the code I cant get to work

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.(pictureid + ".jpg");
```

Where am i going wrong? The error says there is an identifier expected.

Comment: Did you mean `Visual Studio 2010`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` expects an [Image or a descendant thereof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7e7b2kd.aspx) (Bitmap and Metafile objects), which you can use as you coded, if you add the image to your project resources *(edit: I should clarify - to do this, go to Project > Properties > Resources tab and "Add Resource". Don't just drop it in the folder)*:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.face2;
```

If you don't want to include the image in your project, you can use [ImageLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.imagelocation.aspx), which will accept a string rather than an object:

```
pictureBox1.ImageLocation = pictureid + ".jpg"; //assuming you include it in the same folder as the exe
```

You could also do something like this:

```
Image face2 = Image.FromFile(pictureid + ".jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = face2;
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! I had no idea i could refer to the "debug/bin" as the root folder!

Comment: pictureBox1.ImageLocation = pictureid + ".jpg"; Worked great for me! Sorry, i would up the answer but im required for atleast 15 points?! the point system on this website feels somewhat like a game to me.. where people get addicted to how many "points" that have.. sigh....

Thanks all the same raney!!

Comment: Yep - unless a method requires a fully qualified path, it will assume Environment.CurrentDirectory. Glad to hear it worked; feel free to mark as answer, in lieu of voting.